# elegant solution to compare 2 binary tree's, and returning false at the earliest time

Tags: scala, binary-tree

I want to compare 2 binary tree's (in-order), and I want to return as early as possible if they are not the same.

I know you can just traverse both tree's and then compare the output, **but I want a smarter solution to somehow return at the earliest time.**

How would you do this in a elagant way in scala? actors?

Node:

```
case class Node(
  var data: Int,
  left:Option[Node],
  right:Option[Node]
)
```

In my main I have 3 tree's that are currently exactly the same, but just pasting it here so it can be modified if needed:

```
def main( args:Array[String] ) = {
  val tree = Node( (3),
                       None,
                       Some(Node( (5),
                                  Some(Node( (1),
                                       None,
                                       None )),
                               Some(Node( (9),
                                        None,
                                        Some(Node( (15),
                                                   None,
                                                   None )) ))  ))  )

  val tree2 = Node( (3),
                      None,
                      Some(Node( (5),
                                 Some(Node( (1),
                                      None,
                                      None )),
                              Some(Node( (9),
                                       None,
                                       Some(Node( (15),
                                                  None,
                                                  None )) ))  ))  )
  val tree3 = Node( (3),
                      None,
                      Some(Node( (5),
                                 Some(Node( (1),
                                      None,
                                      None )),
                              Some(Node( (9),
                                       None,
                                       Some(Node( (15),
                                                  None,
                                                  None )) ))  ))  )
}
```

Comment: In Java there is the new Fork/Join framework that would allow you to do a concurrent DFS that could bail when it found the first difference. Maybe you could use that for Scala?

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could zip the trees in tuple-2 and use a traversal function that visits the trees in the same way until the tuple's elements diverge. Optionally you could run BFT, DFT in parallel and stop when the first fails.

Answer (score 3):

If you want both a short-circuit in both the comparison and the traversal, you can cast the traversal as a `Stream` generator, `zip` the streams from each traversal and use `forall` or `exists` to detect a mis-match (`forall` and `exists` are short-circuit, stopping as soon as the result is known).

I don't have time to write the code, so if someone more diligent does, give them the check!

Comment: I'm not a scala expert but in any reasonable functional language I'd expect this to be the correct answer. You already have tools to do all of these things and the entire motivation behind the paradigm is simple composition of known-good parts into a known-good whole. Rolling your own comparator that's a crappy version of flatten/zip/fold all at once is missing the point. You might as well go back to java.

Answer (score 1):

Just use recursion.  Except in the case of gigantic trees which are nearly identical, you won't gain anything by using parallelism, so don't bother.  Something like:

```
def same(n: Node, m: Node): Boolean = {
  if (n.data != m.data || 
      n.left.isEmpty != m.left.isEmpty || 
      n.right.isEmpty != m.right.isEmpty) {
    false
  }
  else if (n.left.exists(a => m.left.exists(b => !same(a,b)))) false
  else !n.right.exists(a => m.right.exists(b => !same(a,b)))
}
```

If your trees might be thousands of levels deep, you should switch to a breadth-first tail recursive strategy instead of this properly recursive strategy (by keeping track of every nonempty node on each side at depth n).

Comment: Yeah I want to handle the case of very large trees.

Comment: say it is a very huge tree, and so is the other one but it is a tad smaller.  We could figure out they are different if they have different depths, unless that is an expensive operation big-o wise?

Comment: @Blankman - Trees can have the same depth but be nonidentical, no?  If you get these trees by having a common ancestor and then modifying them, you could add a special hash code field that you update (e.g. by xoring) with the hash code of whatever you add; then you'd only need to traverse the trees if the two hash codes match.  If they're really huge, you should do breadth-first, and use a parallel operation the first time your breadth gets adequately wide (e.g. 16 elements).

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about a similar problem lately. While the algorithm outlined by Randall Schulz would be great (both run-time and stile wise), it does only work if both trees have the same shape.

"at the earliest time" has to be defined more clearly. In general such an algorithm has the the worst case run-time of O(min(n1,n2)) where n1 and n2 are the number of nodes of the two trees. Given a concrete problem, traversal order might influence the run-time a lot.

If the problem is not specified further you might traverse the tree in what ever order you like. In-order comes quite naturally and need no further book keeping. That said, it all boils down to Rex Kerr's approach. I just added my code with pattern matching which might probably a bit easier to understand.

```
def check(tree1:Node,tree2:Node): Boolean = {
    def checkOption(tr1:Option[Node], tr2:Option[Node]) = (tr1,tr2) match {
        case (None, None)         => true
        case (Some(t1), Some(t2)) => check(t1,t2)
        case _                    => false
    }

    (tree1,tree2) match {
        case (Node(d1,l1,r1), Node(d2,l2,r2)) if(d1==d2) => 
            checkOption(l1,l2) && checkOption(r1,r2)
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object Main extends App {

  implicit val executor = ExecutionContext.global
  val branchLevel = 3

  def differentSequential(n1: Node, n2: Node) = differentOpt(Some(n1), Some(n2))

  def differentConcurrent(n1: Node, n2: Node) = differentPar(Some(n1), Some(n2), branchLevel)

  def differentOpt(n1: Option[Node], n2: Option[Node]): Boolean = {
    (n1, n2) match {
      case (Some(Node(d1, l1, r1)), Some(Node(d2, l2, r2))) =>
        d1 != d2 || differentOpt(l1, l2) || differentOpt(r1, r2)
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  def differentPar(n1: Option[Node], n2: Option[Node], level: Int): Future[Boolean] = {
    (n1, n2) match {
      case (Some(Node(d1, l1, r1)), Some(Node(d2, l2, r2))) => {
        if (d1 != d2)
          Future.successful(false)
        else if (level > 0) {
          val leftR = differentPar(l1, l2, level - 1)
          val rightR = differentPar(r1, r2, level - 1)
          combineOr(leftR, rightR)
        } else {
          Future.successful(differentOpt(l1, l2) || differentOpt(r1, r2))
        }
      }

      case _ => Future(false)
    }
  }

  private def combineOr(f1: Future[Boolean], f2: Future[Boolean]): Future[Boolean] = {
    val p = Promise[Boolean]()
    bind(p, f1, f2)
    bind(p, f2, f1)
    p.future
  }

  private def bind(p: Promise[Boolean], f: Future[Boolean], other: Future[Boolean]) {
    f.onComplete {
      case Success(x) => if (!x) p.completeWith(other) else p.trySuccess(true)
      case Failure(t) => p.tryFailure(t)
    }
  }


}
```

DifferentSequential will compare as few nodes as possible and uses simple pattern matching. I also tried a version which starts checking several branches of the tree concurrently.

**NOTE:** This code was not tested